# spring mvc: how to set request timeout when the return type of controller is CompletableFuture?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, java-8, servlet-3.0

If the return type of one controller method is `CompletableFuture`, the result would be completed latter asynchronously, but how to set timeout for this request so that the spring would abort the request if it's not completed in time?

In legacy way, via `AsyncContext`, I could do it. But what about `CompletableFuture` case? I could not find any related doc.

Note that I know the global default timeout setting, but my question is how to set timeout per request.

Comment: Just set a timeout on the CF. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#orTimeout(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

Comment: It's new method since java9. But back to my question, should it be the responsibility of spring to timeout blocking on `future.get()`? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-

Comment: How do you define a version released last year as "new"? Java 11 is out this month! If you're using an obsolete version of Java please tag you question as such.

Comment: I add `java-8` tag on my question. Anyways, how spring handles the `future` behinds the scene? I prefer a quick and correct answer before I dive into the source codes of spring.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer my question.

The processing of `CompletableFuture` is same to `DeferredResult`?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-processing

The spring would do `request.startAsync()` only after the handler method returns, then I think the only way to change timeout is to enable a `AsyncHandlerInterceptor` and do `request.getAsyncContext().setTimeout()` in `afterConcurrentHandlingStarted()`?

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/AsyncHandlerInterceptor.html#afterConcurrentHandlingStarted-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-java.lang.Object-

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public  void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new AsyncHandlerInterceptor() {
      @Override
      public void afterConcurrentHandlingStarted(HttpServletRequest request,
          HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        request.getAsyncContext().setTimeout(myTimeoutInMillisHere);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

please note that the timeout can be configured through `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout` property.

For example `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout: "180s"` set it to 3 minutes